# Скрыть многострочный контент

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть такой код

```css
div {width: 100px;}
p {float: left;}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>Item 1</p>
  <p>Item 2</p>
  <p>Item 3</p>
  <p>Item 4</p>
  <p>Item 5</p>
  <p>Item 6</p>
</div>
<div>
  <button>Show All</button>
</div>
```

Вопрос, можно ли как-то при помощи CSS и/или JS/jQuery оставить видимой только первую строку, а остальные показывать только при клике по кнопке. Ширина содержимого тега `<p>` динамическая (элементы берутся из базы) и жестко забить отображать только первые n элементов я не могу

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(function() {
  $('.container').each(function() {
    var items = $('div > p', this)
      , offset = items.eq(0).offset().top
      , button = $('button', this);
    items.each(function() {
      $(this).offset().top === offset && $(this).addClass('top-line');
    });
    button.click(function() {
      if ('collapsed' === button.data('state')) {
        button.data('state', 'expanded').text('Show less');
        items.show();
      }
      else {
        button.data('state', 'collapsed').text('Show more');
        items.hide().filter('.top-line').show();
      }
    }).click();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid;
  margin-bottom: 1em;
  padding: 1em;
}

.container div {
  clear: left;
}

.container-1 div.items {
  width: 50px;
}

.container-2 div.items {
  width: 100px;
}

.container-3 div.items {
  width: 150px;
}

p {
  float: left;
  padding-right: .5em;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container container-1">
  <div class="items">
    <p>Item 1</p><p>Item 2</p><p>Item 3</p><p>Item 4</p><p>Item 5</p><p>Item 6</p>
  </div>
  <div><button>Show more</button></div>
</div>
<div class="container container-2">
  <div class="items">
    <p>Item 1</p><p>Item 2</p><p>Item 3</p><p>Item 4</p><p>Item 5</p><p>Item 6</p>
  </div>
  <div><button>Show more</button></div>
</div>
<div class="container container-3">
  <div class="items">
    <p>Item 1</p><p>Item 2</p><p>Item 3</p><p>Item 4</p><p>Item 5</p><p>Item 6</p>
  </div>
  <div><button>Show more</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое. Ответ точно на мой вопрос. Теперь нужно подумать не исказил ли я вопросом исходную задачу :)